# WPF default button not working when datagrid row is selected

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, datagrid, defaultbutton

I have used a `Datagrid` and a button(`btnAdd`) in `WPF`.The button is default.I need to call `btnAdd_Click`(which uses the selected row of the `Datagrid`) when `Enter` key is pressed.

In other words i need to select a row & press `Enter` & do the work done by `btnAdd_Click`.

```
<Button  Name="btnAdd"  Click="btnAdd_Click" IsDefault="True" TabIndex="4" >Add to List</Button>
```

Comment: i'm not sure i get it , you want to call btnAdd_Click() when the user press Enter ?

Comment: yes, that's what i want.

Comment: thing is when a row is selected pressing `Enter` selects next row.i want to call `btnAdd_Click` with the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the PreviewKeyDown
and mark e.Handeled = true

dg = DataGrid

```
    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        dg.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(dg_PreviewKeyDown);
        base.OnInitialized(e);
    }

    void dg_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (Key.Enter == e.Key)
        {
            btnAdd_Click();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```